# Check uppercase AND lowercase

Tags: regex

I'm searching from a while for the regular expression that matches a word containing between 8 and 20 characters combining uppercases AND lowercases:

Here an example of valid expression : AaAaAaAaA or aaaaaaaaA

Not Valid expression example : aaaaaaaaa or AAAAAAAA

What I did till now is : ^[a-z][A-Z]{8,20}$, but as you can see, that doesn't work

Somebody have an idea for that ?

Best regards

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Credit to anubhava, lookahead was the way to go.

```
\b(?=[a-z]+[A-Z]+|[A-Z]+[a-z]+)[a-zA-Z]{8,20}\b
```

The look ahead ensures that there is at least one capital and lowercase letter in any order in the match.  This will match whole words that are 8-20 chars long and contain at least 1 upper case and at least 1 lower case letter.

```
^(?=[a-z]+[A-Z]+|[A-Z]+[a-z]+)[a-zA-Z]{8,20}$
```

Will anchor to the beginning and end of the string, and thus match only a single word.

You can see it in action here http://regex101.com/r/uE5lT4/4

Edit: First version did not match a word if the only capital was the last letter.

Answer (score 3):

Your character class needs to include both `a-z` and `A-Z` ranges. Regex should be:

```
^[a-zA-Z]{8,20}$
```

Your regex:

```
^[a-z][A-Z]{8,20}$
```

is actually checking for a lower case character followed by 8 to 20 upper case alphabets.

**Update:** to make sure you match at least one lower and one upper case alphabet use lookahead regex like this:

```
^(?=[A-Z]*[a-z])(?=[a-z]*[A-Z])[a-zA-Z]{8,20}$
```

#### [RegEx Demo](http://regex101.com/r/yF8oY0/1)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I already tried that and doesn't work. Because like that even the expression aaaaaaaaa matches. In my case I need to check if an expression contains lower and uppercase at the same time. thanks

Comment: Sorry but it's still not working :(
here a web site where you can test it : http://regex101.com/

Comment: I updated my answer with correct regex and a working demo link.